# Can I install linux on my HDD and GRUB on a thumb drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub, elementary-os

I would like to know if it is possible for me to install ElementaryOS alongside Windows 10 but not replace or touch my Windows 10 bootloader at all.  I don't want to turn my computer on and see a GRUB screen asking which OS I would like to boot to, I want to be able to have GRUB on a thumb drive so whenever I would like to boot to Linux I can just plug in a thumb drive, select it in BIOS and go from there.  IT doesn't like Linux so I need to make sure they don't discover it exists by accident.  I can hide that partition from windows explorer in the registry, so all that I have to do is hide it from any bootloaders.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously you can, I did it before, around 2 year back, xubuntu and win 8. Select the proper locations to install grub and bootloader. It may be a bit tricky with UEFI based machines. I cant write a full answer right now, so   shared my experience as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works, I have a similar setup. First make sure you make a backup of the original master boot record before you start (and after you repartitioned the harddisk), just in case.

Then it's only a matter of installing the grub bootloader to your USB stick and change the BIOS settings to have the USB stick with higher priority than the harddisk.

Comment: Nice one :) , BIOS or UEFI ?l